# Confusion in the explanation of Gauss’ Divergence theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, gauss-law, vector-fields, calculus

[image]

This is taken from Mathematical Methods Arfken.  Firstly Look at the highlighted text.

Now I have a confusion which is that if divergence of vector $\mathbf{A}$ is not zero at all points lying inside the closed surface, then there must be a source or sink at a point for the vector field of $\mathbf{A}$.

If that point, say $P$, doesn’t lie on the surface and instead lies inside of the closed surface then it must be enclosed in one of the infinitesimal parallelepipeds, and from that parallelepiped, the net inward flux won’t be equal to outward, as its a source. So its contribution shouldn’t be zero.

So why is it taken so here?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the individual contribution from a single parallelepiped does not have to be zero. However, the point here is that the *total* contribution from all the interior parallelepipeds is zero. Consider an interior parallelepiped and one of its boundaries. Any vector coming out of this boundary must go into a neighboring parallelepiped. Therefore, it creates equal and opposite contributions to the two parallelepipeds which cancel out.

This argument rests on the underlying assumption that the vector field in question is [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function). A function $f(x)$ is continuous at a point $p$ if

1. It is defined at $p$
2. Its limit $\lim \limits_{x \to p} f(x)$ exists and is equal to $f(p)$.

If a vector field has an abrupt change somewhere (which means that it is not continuous), it will not create equal and opposite contributions to every interior parallelepiped and this argument will not work.

Comment: You want the derivatives of the vector field to be continuous, so that the divergence is continuous.

Comment: @Pedro That's not necessarily true. For example, the electric field of a point charge $\hat{\mathbf{r}}/r^2$ has zero divergence everywhere except the origin where the divergence is infinite. The divergence theorem still holds.

Comment: It does not hold, not in the usual sense at least. You can make it look like it holds by thinking of the divergence as a distribution (rather than an honest function), but that is going beyond what the theorem says. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement